# Ruta de acesso incorrecta

Tags: java, java-swing, eclipse, imagen, nullpointerexception

Que tengan un muy buen dia comunidad.

Es la primera vez que escribo  y tambien coincide con mis inicios en la programacion.
Estoy estudiando de manera autodidacta y nose si alguien de aca, tambien intento iniciarse con la "Gekkepedia de Ernesto". El asunto es que hoy empeze el proyecto final que da en su curso, que es un sistema vacacional.
Voy al punto. El codigo en general esta bien pero Eclipse, me tira este error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at SVacacional.<init>(SVacacional.java:14)
at SVacacional.main(SVacacional.java:61)
```

Por lo que entiendo hay un error en la ruta de acesso a las imagenes que quiero subir. Mis imagenes estan Escritorio-Proyecto-images

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class SVacacional extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JLabel label1, label2, label3, label4;
private JTextField fila1;
private JButton boton1;

public SVacacional() {
setLayout(null);
setTitle(" Bienvenido ");    //TITULO
getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255,0,0));
setIconImage(new 
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/icon.png")).getImage());

ImageIcon imagen=new ImageIcon("images/logo-coca.png");
label1= new JLabel(imagen);
label1.setBounds(25, 15, 300, 150);
add(label1);

label2=new JLabel("Sistema de control vacacional");
label2.setBounds(35, 135, 300, 30);
label2.setFont(new Font("Andale mono", 3, 18));
label2.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255)); 
add(label2);

label3=new JLabel("Por favor, ingrese su nombre");
label3.setBounds(45, 212, 200, 30);
label3.setFont(new Font("Andale mono", 1, 12));
label3.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
add(label3);

label4=new JLabel("®2019 Developer Evolution");
label4.setBounds(85, 375, 300, 30);
label4.setFont(new Font("Andale mono", 1, 12));
label4.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
add(label4);

fila1=new JTextField();
fila1.setBounds(45, 240, 255, 25);
fila1.setBackground(new Color(224,224,224));
fila1.setFont(new Font("Andale mono", 1, 14));
fila1.setForeground(new Color(255,0,0));
add(fila1);

boton1=new JButton("Ingresar");
boton1.setBounds(125, 280, 100, 30);
boton1.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
boton1.setFont(new Font("Andale mono", 1, 14));
boton1.setForeground(new Color(255,0,0));
boton1.addActionListener(this);
add(fila1);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if(e.getSource()==boton1) {

}
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SVacacional vacaciones=new SVacacional();
    vacaciones.setBounds(0, 0, 350, 450);
    vacaciones.setVisible(true);
    vacaciones.setResizable(false);
    vacaciones.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

}

introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: Hola! no adjuntes tu código en una imagen, sino, como código, ya que así puede visualizarse mejor

Comment: Tienes razon, no lo habia notado jajaj soy un novato. Ahi lo subo

Comment: si crees que no es un duplicado intenta agregar el sistema de construcción que usas y las estructura de carpetas de tu proyecto

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que tu error, se deba a un error de la ruta del archivo, podrías indicar la ruta de la siguiente manera:

```
Image image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/logo-coca.png")).getImage();
```

De esta manera solo tienes que indicar la subcarpeta donde se encuentra tu imagen dentro de la carpeta "src" o como la hayas nombrado.